# JSON - find element

Tags: jquery, json

I have JSON that looks like this -

```
[{
    "Columnd58eae9aee6a43b9836e59254e914f43": 1,
    "Metric": "7e70661f-e266-4745-9b1b-c5c5691e9746",
    "MetricDisplay": "Active Users",
    "Pivot1": 40.00000,
    "Pivot2": 38.00000,
    "Pivot3": 18.00000,
    "Total": 96.00000,
    "Average": 32.00000,
    "IsTotal": 0,
    "MetricOrder": 1
}]
```

but in this example I have 3 "Pivot" columns, there could and most likely will be more. How do I determine the number of Pivot columns I have and the values for those elements using jQuery?

Comment: you can iterate over the KEYS of an object with a `for (var key in object) {...}` loop. You can then check the format of "key".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ideally, you'd use an array:

```
Pivot: [ 40.00, 38.00, 18.00, ... ],
```

But you could solve this using bracket notation, something like this:

```
var i = 1;
while (data['Pivot' + i]) {
    console.log(data['Pivot' + i]);
    i++;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Change your structure of `Pivot` to an array:

```
var obj = [{
    "Columnd58eae9aee6a43b9836e59254e914f43": 1,
    "Metric": "7e70661f-e266-4745-9b1b-c5c5691e9746",
    "MetricDisplay": "Active Users",
    "Pivots": [40.00000, 38.00000, 18.00000],
    "Total": 96.00000,
    "Average": 32.00000,
    "IsTotal": 0,
    "MetricOrder": 1
}]
```

This way, you can find the length of the `Pivots` element using either of the following:

```
obj["Pivots"].length
obj.Pivots.length
```

Answer (score 0):

If `Pivot` key keep same manner then you can try this code to find get Pivot values

```
var jsonData = [{
        "Columnd58eae9aee6a43b9836e59254e914f43": 1,
        "Metric": "7e70661f-e266-4745-9b1b-c5c5691e9746",
        "MetricDisplay": "Active Users",
        "Pivot1": 40.00000,
        "Pivot2": 38.00000,
        "Pivot3": 18.00000,
        "Total": 96.00000,
        "Average": 32.00000,
        "IsTotal": 0,
        "MetricOrder": 1
    }];
    var arr = $.map(jsonData[0], function(value, index){ 
        if(/^(\Pivot)[0-9]+$/.test(index)){
            return value;
        }

      });
    console.log(arr);

    //[40, 38, 18]
```

Answer (score 0):

JSON format you have provided is not a valid one.

I made a slight modification.

```
 {
  "item": {
    "Columnd58eae9aee6a43b9836e59254e914f43": "1",
    "Metric": "7e70661f-e266-4745-9b1b-c5c5691e9746",
    "MetricDisplay": "Active Users",
    "pivot": {
      "Pivot1": "40",
      "Pivot2": "38",
      "Pivot3": "18"
    },
    "Total": "96",
    "Average": "32",
    "IsTotal": "0",
    "MetricOrder": "1"
  }
};
```

Object.keys(x.item.pivot).length

This will gives the required length!!